# handle mouse events on togglebutton wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, togglebutton

Okay. I am trying on and off mouse events on the click of the toggle button in wpf. so far this is what i have..
the xaml is as follows

```
 <telerik:RadToggleButton Name="Percentage" Height="25" Width="25" Style="{StaticResource SelectionGridStyle}" Checked="Percentage_Click"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
     <telerik:RadToggleButton.ToolTip>
         <ToolTip Content="{localization:Translate Percentage}"></ToolTip>
     </telerik:RadToggleButton.ToolTip>
 </telerik:RadToggleButton>
```

the this is the code behind.

```
  private void Percentage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      RadToggleButton btn = sender as RadToggleButton;
      btn.IsChecked = true;


       //if (e.Handled == true)
       //    e.Handled = false;
       //else if(e.Handled == false)
       //    e.Handled = true;
   }
```

i want to handle the drag of a mouse for selection purpose when on else off. is there i way to achieve this?? Thank you.

Comment: Yes there is... search google for the many online tutorials. Stack Overflow is where you come when you have a programming problem with a particular part of your code... it is *not* where you can come to search for third party code or tutorials. As such, I am voting to close your question.

Comment: ohh its been done. but thanks...